# Postfix Increment in While Loop Javascript

Tags: javascript, while-loop, increment

Could anybody explain to me please why this loop

```
let i = 0
while (i < 5) {
    i++
    console.log(i)  
}
```

shows 1,2,3,4,5 ?

As I know postfix increment returns the old value, right? so first shouldn't it log 0 into the console?

Thank you

Comment: Postfix increment does return the old value, but you aren't *using* the value returned from `i++`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is true, when executing as one statement. You have separated it in 2 lines, so 2 statements, each one is executed sequentially

---

The following code would do it

```js
let i = 0
while (i < 5) {
    console.log(i++)  
}
console.log("===============")
i = 0
while (i < 5) {
    a = i++
    console.log(a)  
}
```

---

Whereas the prefix increment does 12345

```js
let i = 0
while (i < 5) {
    console.log(++i)  
}
console.log("===============")
i = 0
while (i < 5) {
    a = ++i
    console.log(a)  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before printing to the console, the code does this: `i++`, which increments `i`. Then, the code prints the value of `i`, which is now 1.